# How to get the decimal places of a number in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, math

I wondered if there is a function to provide clean solution to getting the amount of decimal places or checking if a number has decimal places in Dart/Flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I've done it:

```
static int getDecimalPlaces(var number) {
  int decimals = 0;
  List<String> substr = number.toString().split('.');
  if (substr.length > 0) decimals = int.tryParse(substr[1]);
  return decimals;
}

static bool hasDecimalPlaces(var number) {
  String <List> substr = number.toString().split('.');
  return (substr.length > 1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should check if it contains it at all.

This returns how many decimals you got:

```
getNumberOfDecimals(String number) {
    if (number.contains('.')) {
    return number.substring(number.indexOf('.')+1).length;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A bit more elegant answer. You split the string at the decimal point and check the length of the 2nd string.

```
getNumberOfDecimals(String number) {
    if (number.contains('.')) {
    return number.split(".")[1].length;
  }
  return 0;
}
```